# Progress slick slider dots с видео и автовоспроизведением

Tags: jquery, slick.js

Есть [slick slider](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) с autoplay и видео:

```js
if ($('.slider').length) {
  $('.slider').each(function() {

    var $this = $(this);


    $this.on('init', function(event) {
      $(".video").each(function(i, e) {
        e.play();
      });
    });

    $this.slick({
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      dots: true,
      infinite: true,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 3000
    });




    function reloadBGVid() {
      $(".video").each(function(i, e) {
        if (e.paused) e.play();
      });
    }

  });
}
```

```css
.slider,
.item {
  height: 20rem;
}

.item img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.slick-dots {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1rem;
  left: 4rem;
}

.slick-dots li {
  width: 1.75rem;
  height: 1.75rem;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 0px;
  line-height: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 5px;
  opacity: .8;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.slick-dots li button {
  font-size: 0px;
  line-height: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  background: red;
}

.slider .slick-dots li:hover,
.slider .slick-dots li.slick-active {
  background-color: #a08a7f;
}

.slider .slick-dots li.slick-active~li {
  background-size: 0% 0%;
}


/* .slider .slick-dots li.slick-active{
  -webkit-animation:right 3s ease-in-out forwards;
  -moz-animation:right 3s ease-in-out forwards;
  -o-animation:right 3s ease-in-out forwards;
  animation:right 3s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes right{
  0%{
    background-size:0% 100%;
  }

  100%{
    background-size:100% 100%;
  }
} */

.slider .slick-dots li.slick-active button {
  -webkit-animation: rightB 3s ease-in-out forwards;
  -moz-animation: rightB 3s ease-in-out forwards;
  -o-animation: rightB 3s ease-in-out forwards;
  animation: rightB 3s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes rightB {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" integrity="sha256-UK1EiopXIL+KVhfbFa8xrmAWPeBjMVdvYMYkTAEv/HI=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js" integrity="sha256-NXRS8qVcmZ3dOv3LziwznUHPegFhPZ1F/4inU7uC8h0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="slider">
  <div class="item">
    <video class="video" muted loop preload>
        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
          
      </video>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQu4CgFeghuoip9xGUET9Ebm4SHUoEHb35dVx1gtVv_Vrfv1i-5&usqp=CAU" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoaWt.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

На dots переключении реализован прогресс.

**Вопрос:** Как реализовать автовоспроизведение slick slider с учетом видео (т.е. при переключении на слайд с видео - воспроизведение слайда не 3 с, а до конца видео) и прогрессом на dots ?

Comment: добавь ссылку на документацию слайдера :)

Comment: видео может быть только в первом слайде? или где угодно?

Comment: @Grundy , где угодно

Comment: длина видео тоже любая может быть? При скрытии видео - оно должно останавливаться?

Comment: @Grundy да видео может быть разной длины и при перелистывании оно останавливается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже встроенного автоизменения времени автоплея нет, однако можно сэмулировать.

Для этого нужно:

1. проверить, что на текущем слайде есть видео
2. если его нет - выставить стандартный интервал 3 секунды
3. если есть

   1. остановить автоплей
   2. получить длительность видео
   3. установить длительность анимации на точке
   4. запустить автоплей
   5. запустить видео

Для получения длительности видео можно воспользоваться [свойством duration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/duration). Однако, оно может быть не заполнено, в этом случае можно подписаться на [событие loadedmetadata](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/loadedmetadata_event) и внутри обработчика уже использовать данное свойство.

Пример реализации:

```js
function defaultAutoplay(slick) {
  slick.options.autoplaySpeed = 3 * 1000;
  slick.play();
}

function videoAutoplay(slick, index, videoDuration, inited) {
  slick.options.autoplaySpeed = videoDuration * 1000;
  slick.play();
  if (!inited) {
    slick.$dots.find(`li:nth-child(${index+1}) button`)
      .css('animation-duration', `${videoDuration}s`)
      .addClass('inited-video');
  }
}

function processVideo(slick, index, video, inited) {
  slick.pause();

  if (isFinite(video.duration)) {
    video.play();
    return videoAutoplay(slick, index, video.duration, inited);
  }

  video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
    videoAutoplay(slick, index, video.duration, inited);
  });
  video.play();
}

if ($('.slider').length) {
  $('.slider').each(function() {

    var $this = $(this);
    $this.on('init', function(event, slick) {
      var video = slick.$slides[slick.currentSlide].querySelector('video');
      if (!video) {
        return defaultAutoplay(slick);
      }

      processVideo(slick, slick.currentSlide, video);

    });

    $this.on('beforeChange', function(e, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
      var video = slick.$slides[nextSlide].querySelector('video');
      if (!video) {
        return defaultAutoplay(slick);
      }

      var inited = slick.$dots.find(`li:nth-child(${nextSlide+1}) button`)
        .hasClass('inited-video');
      processVideo(slick, nextSlide, video, inited);
    });

    $this.slick({
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      dots: true,
      infinite: true,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 3000
    });
  });
}
```

```css
.slider,
.item {
  height: 20rem;
}

.item img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.slick-dots {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1rem;
  left: 4rem;
}

.slick-dots li {
  width: 1.75rem;
  height: 1.75rem;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 0px;
  line-height: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 5px;
  opacity: .8;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.slick-dots li button {
  font-size: 0px;
  line-height: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  background: red;
}

.slider .slick-dots li:hover,
.slider .slick-dots li.slick-active {
  background-color: #a08a7f;
}

.slider .slick-dots li.slick-active~li {
  background-size: 0% 0%;
}


/* .slider .slick-dots li.slick-active{
  -webkit-animation:right 3s ease-in-out forwards;
  -moz-animation:right 3s ease-in-out forwards;
  -o-animation:right 3s ease-in-out forwards;
  animation:right 3s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes right{
  0%{
    background-size:0% 100%;
  }

  100%{
    background-size:100% 100%;
  }
} */

.slider .slick-dots li.slick-active button {
  -webkit-animation: rightB 3s ease-in-out forwards;
  -moz-animation: rightB 3s ease-in-out forwards;
  -o-animation: rightB 3s ease-in-out forwards;
  animation: rightB 3s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes rightB {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" integrity="sha256-UK1EiopXIL+KVhfbFa8xrmAWPeBjMVdvYMYkTAEv/HI=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="slider">
  <div class="item">
    <video class="video" muted preload>
        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
          
      </video>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQu4CgFeghuoip9xGUET9Ebm4SHUoEHb35dVx1gtVv_Vrfv1i-5&usqp=CAU" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <video class="video" muted preload>
        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
          
      </video>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoaWt.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```